# Type hinting pairwise with overhang

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-typing

I took over a code base (support down to 3.9) and wanted to add some type hinting. However I am currently stuck at this function.

```
def _pairwise(iterable: T.Iterable, end=None) -> T.Iterable:
    left, right = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(right, None)
    return itertools.zip_longest(left, right, fillvalue=end)
```

Which is later used to iterate over regex matches and extract their start and end indices for slicing. The last fill value of `None` is used to have the last slice go to the end of the string.

We know that the actual signature should be

`_pairwise(iterable: Iterable[T], end: Optional[T] = None) -> Iterator[tuple[T, Optional[T]]]`

because `left` is guaranteed to be at least as long as `right`.

However the approach with the `zip_longest` does not allow that. Type checkers read that as `Iterator[Optional[T], Optional[T]]`.

I have rewritten the function so that the type checker (pyright) is able to verify that target signature.

```
def _pairwise(
    iterable: Iterable[T], end: Optional[T] = None
) -> Iterator[tuple[T, Optional[T]]]:
    left, right = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(right, None)
    for x, y in zip(right, left):
        yield y, x
    if (last := next(left, None)) is not None:
        yield last, end
```

However I am not particularly pleased with this result yet. First the need to swap the arguments to `zip` to avoid it taking one extra step on `left` as well as the manual check to deal with the case of the argument being an empty iterable.

This also means that the functionality is not the intended one for `T=NoneType` although that is not actually a problem, but it does annoy me a bit.

Is there any other way to get this pairwise functionality to typecheck?

Comment: In your last implementation you can `yield from` instead of `for...yield` to clean code further, but I'd just put an ignore comment - this is clearly just a typing limitation, there's nothing wrong with ignore comments if you explain them. You could also `itertools.chain` right iterable with `[end]` and use `zip`, that should also typecheck.

Comment: @STerliakov I can not yield directly yield from as i have to swap the order of the elements in the yield  to not have zip eat the last element of `left`. But i guess you are right. I should probably just ignore the typing error.

I think i would use this if i could do yield from and did not need that check for the empty iterable.

Comment: Would [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=b91dba87507c30c384463abe135f8236) work for you? This should be almost the same in terms of efficiency and typechecks cleanly. I'd argue that this expresses the intent even better than `zip_longest`, since you know for sure which of iterables is longer (not shorter, to be strict).

Comment: @STerliakov that also looks good. How does this behave when the iterable is empty to begin with?

Seems to do fine because then zip just instantly stops because the left side raises StopIteration.

Seems to be the perfect solution thanks.
If you want to write it up as a proper answer i will give you the check mark.
Otherwise i will so that everyone can see it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `zip_longest` solution looks clean to me, and `# type: ignore[return-value]` would be a good fit there, probably with a short explanatory comment.

However, to make your code typecheck, you could use plain `zip` and add "filler" entry to the end manually like this:

```py
import itertools
from typing import Iterable, Iterator, TypeVar, Optional

T = TypeVar('T')


def _pairwise(
    iterable: Iterable[T], end: Optional[T] = None
) -> Iterator[tuple[T, Optional[T]]]:
    left, right = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(right, None)
    return zip(left, itertools.chain(right, [end]))
```

Now `mypy` is [happy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=b91dba87507c30c384463abe135f8236) about this code, and you're slightly more explicit: you know that second iterable (`right`) is one element shorter than `left` unless `iterable` was empty, thus appending one item will make them equal. In case of empty input both implementation produce an empty iterator.