# itertools.pairwise backwards compatibility and a dubious Pylance warning

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-typing

[The `pairwise` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) was added to `itertools` in Python version 3.10.

I would like to use that function or, where not available, define my own function based on the documented recipe.

I did this:

```
import itertools

try:
    _pairwise = itertools.pairwise # Pylance doesn't like this
except AttributeError:
    def _pairwise(iterable):
        a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)
```

In this way, I can call _pairwise which will be the out-of-the-box implementation on Python versions from 3.10 onwards. Earlier versions will use the recipe implementation.

I use VS Code and Pylance.

Pylance underlines `itertools.pairwise` and reports as follows:

```
Expression of type "type[pairwise[_T_co@pairwise]]" cannot be assigned to declared type "(iterable: Unknown) -> zip[tuple[Unknown, Unknown]]"
```

However, having tested this code on 3.9 and 3.12 I deduce that it's not a problem at all.

I know I can suppress the warning with `#type: ignore`

Is there a technique that I could use (maybe *should* use) that would not induce this warning or do I just have to live with it?

Comment: It's inferring the variable type based on the implementation, which has no type hinting at all. Have you tried a more explicit type, for either the variable (before either assignment) or the implementation?

Comment: What happen if you use the typing close to the one of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77238976/11832127?

Comment: @ndclt Adding type hints to the function definition doesn't help

Comment: I feel like functools.wraps would be a good way to fix it, but I'm not sure how it could be added without breaking functionality for <3.10. The error would probably go away if you did @wraps(itertools.pairwise) but it would throw the attributerror when running for lower python versions.

Comment: Perhaps you could do a check like if hasattr(itertools, "pairwise") and then setattr to put in your function as the attribute it might lead to better code where that part is not type checked and you use itertools.pairwise instead of _pairwise in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a suggestion from @armansa I find this to be a cleaner solution:

```
import itertools

def _pairwise(iterable):
        a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

if not hasattr(itertools, "pairwise"):
    setattr(itertools, "pairwise", _pairwise)
```

Then, subsequently make the call as:

```
itertools.pairwise(myIterableGoesHere)
```